# Whether creating Opencart custom theme is necessary?

Tags: wordpress, opencart, opencart2.x

I was working in wordpress and now I have to work in opencart theme customization. In wordpress, creating child theme is safer to override .

Here in opencart, is it necessary to create a custom theme to override the default theme?

I'm customizing default theme only, not creating a custom theme. Any advantage or disadvantage to this?

Comment: Updating will replace files so it will cause problem, if you don't want to update, then you can do whatever you want which i dont recommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not customize the default theme. You should copy the default theme to a new theme, and customize that. If a page is not found in the custom theme, opencart uses the page of default theme. So best practice is that you should not change the default theme. Instead make a copy of it and use that.

Comment: ok i take this as helpful since u answered many opencart qns ;)

Comment: I have been working in opencart since 2 years now. Developed several modules and extensions.